# when I try to "sync project with gradle files" a warning pops up

Tags: android-studio

```
Warning: Mapping new ns schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns /schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
```

Comment: For reference there are two issues in Google tracker you can star:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184759551
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190535786

Answer (score 77):

this changes work for me with last gradle version 7.3.3

just edit this versions and build your app

**android/build.gradle**

```html
buildscript {
   repositories {
       ...
   }

   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
      ...
   }
}
```

**`android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`**

```html
...
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip
```

Comment: work for me , thank

Comment: this did the trick

Comment: This alone didn't work for me. I got an error about the "android:exported". What I did to fix it is going into the android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml and add "android:exported="true" in all the "activity" that didn't have it (just one in my case). Take a look at this to understand it further: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported
I've got the info from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67654506/manifest-merger-failed-targeting-android-12/67668116#67668116 and here http://shorturl.at/mCEX7

Answer (score 23):

What works for me is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/70035679/17825313

But I could not find that menu in my AndroidStudio so have to update the content of these 2 files directly:

Basically just use the latest gradle plugin and gradle version and make sure they both match according to the official doc

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
       ...
   }

   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
      ...
   }
}
```

**android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
... 
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
```

Comment: definitely cleaned my problem!!! Thank you!!! It also forced the build to also notice Android-31 SDK because gradle knows about that version!

Answer (score 14):

Issue seems to be related to `buildToolsVersion`. Changing it from:

```
compileSdkVersion(30)
buildToolsVersion("30.0.3")
```

To:

```
compileSdkVersion(30)
buildToolsVersion("30.0.2")
```

Fixed it to me (syntax may change if you're not using `.gradle.kts` file or `gradle version >= gradle-7.0`, but the idea is the same)

(AndroidStudio will show: `Old buildToolsVersion 30.0.2; recommended version is 30.0.3 or later` in build file. But the Warnings will be gone from gradle building logs.)

Comment: Why is `buildToolsVersion` needed at all?  The project compiles fine without it.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky buildToolsVersion is always used. Simply, if you don't write it, it will use the default buildToolsVersion of the SDK.

Comment: yeah :D, it's exactly what @KJNewtown said. 

Probably what was happening here is that android plugin was outdated with something (not sure what), and it was generating the warning. Changes are this will be automatically gone in the future

Comment: where I have put this? @GuilhermeV.

Comment: @BagusKurnianto in your build.gradle file, update it inside your "android" section

Comment: `buildTools` definition is no longer required, it defaults to the latest available version and downloads it automatically from Google if it is not installed yet

Comment: `buildToolsVersion("30.0.2")` is not available in neither of the `build.gradle` files!. But if the case is as @nuhkoca said, then that didn’t work somehow and I’m facing the same issue.

Comment: I've posted it a while back, the versions could have changed already. Make sure to have A.S updated, as well the plugins. If it still doesn't work, try to include the buildToolsVersion(...) instead of using the default as nuhkoca suggested :D

Comment: It works after I update my module build.gradle to android {
    compileSdk 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"    defaultConfig {.....}

Answer (score 13):

The mismatch is due to:

- Android Gradle Plugin Version
- Gradle Version

Match them as per the gradle plugin releases

Ref: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

[image: Android Gradle Plugin Version and Gradle Version]

And the warnings will go away.
cheers.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem (using VS Code)
and searched global (ctrl+shift+F):
`compileSdkVersion`
and instead of:

```
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
```

I changed it:

```
    compileSdkVersion 30
```

this worked for me, now it runs without the warning!

Comment: this doesn't work anymore since few dependencies could require to bump it to 31

Answer (score 2):

Your **android SDK version and emulator API level** must be the same.

If you are using the Android SDK version is 31 and trying to run over emulator API level 30 it would cause you some complications.

You must use the **same level** for both (android SDK and API level) to avoid many complications.

Answer (score 2):

Project Structure > Project and change Android Gradle Plugin Version to `7.0.3` or higher if available and Gradle Version to `7.3` or higher if available

Answer (score 1):

I had a project showing this warnings. The `Gradle Version` was set to `7.0.2` and `Android Gradle Plugin Version` to `4.2.2`. After changing the `Android Gradle Plugin Version` to `7.0.3` the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding a dependency on `android/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, you can **completely delete the android file** and still **run the project**.

Or in file **..\android\build.gradle** change

```
dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
  .
  .
}
```

To the **new version** like

```
dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
  .
  .
}
```

And in file `..\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` change

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

To the **new version** like

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

Faced this problem while working on a udemy project [xylophone_flutter](https://github.com/londonappbrewery/xylophone-flutter.git)

Was getting below warnings while launching the app

```
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
```

My flutter version is 3.16.9

```
flutter --version
Flutter 3.16.9 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
```

And my dart version is 3.2.6

```
  dart --version
Dart SDK version: 3.2.6 (stable) (Wed Jan 24 13:41:58 2024 +0000) on "macos_x64"
```

The gradle wrapper version I am using is 7.5

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```

And I had below in the `android/build.gradle`

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    }
```

which is not up to date with the latest gradle version.

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
    }
```

This solved the problem and warnings are removed.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same isuue. Update your Gradle to latest version and update `buildToolsVersion("30.0.3")` to 4 or :10 in `build.gradle` (Module) file in android.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
compileSdkVersion(30)
buildToolsVersion("30.0.1")
```

instead of

```
compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
```

in app/build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

add this to dependencies in build.gradle

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By updating your `android/build.gradle` fixed these warnings:

#### Example:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```