# Manifest Merge Failed with multiple errors: Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**I have tired every solutions from stack overflow which i can find but still im not able to solve this error.**

**This is my manifest file**

`xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.nativecheckoutsdk">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.NativeCheckoutSDK">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>`

**Errors in Merged Manifest are given below **

*Merging Errors: Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. NativeCheckoutSDK.app main manifest (this file)
Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. NativeCheckoutSDK.app main manifest (this file)

> - 

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: the answer provided below help me solve the error @c-an

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [Android 12](https://tedblob.com/android-12-safer-component-exporting/), a component must explicitly have android:exported true or false. The components in the third-party libraries may not have the android:exported tag. You can check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67668116/17147888) to find the component causing the issue.

Comment: This helped for me!!! THANK YOU :)