# Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I have a problem with a manifest file, error message:

> Manifest merger failed : android: exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android: exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

My AndroidManifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:exported="true"
            android:name=".Activities.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67654506/manifest-merger-failed-targeting-android-12/67668116#67668116) describes a solution but it doesn't work or I made something wrong. Maybe anyone has a similar problem, please let me know how to resolve that.

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. downgrade or upgrade to a prior sdk version then rebuild the project.
2. open your project's `AndroidManifest.xml`.
3. click on the Merged Manifest tab [at the bottom of the window]
4. find out which `<activity>` that includes an `<intent-filter>` tag is missing the `android:exported` attribute
5. if found then right-click and press `Go to Declaration` then add `android:exported` attribute to the activity tag
6. Rebuild the project

Hope it will work. It works for me.

Comment: Yes, it works fine for me to. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Related to the first answer I could add in the 5 step:

5. Add into the <activity tag: android:exported="true"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).