# How I can fix "Warning: Mapping new ns" about flutter in vsc

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I try this one
[when I try to "sync project with gradle files" a warning pops up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66992420/when-i-try-to-sync-project-with-gradle-files-a-warning-pops-up)
but I can't find buildToolsVersion

and
I try to search for solution for fix this problem
the other is download gradle
but I can't install anywhere

then
please help me to fix this problem
thankyou for your kindness

https://www.img.in.th/image/PQZxbH

Comment: did you find any issue while running `flutter doctor`?

Comment: No issues found!
it all green

Answer (score 0):

ensure your sdk version and build version match up, I had the same issues because my build version in android/app/build.gradle targetSDKVersion wasn't the same as my sdk version in my emulator. I now have them both set to 30 and this went away

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little bit late for you but I write a solution for this problem for those who have the same problem:

1. Go to **android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties** and add the replace the **distributionUrl=....** with the following line:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip`

2. Go to **android/build.gradle** and replace the **com.android.tools.build** line with the following:

`buildscript { dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1' } }`

3. Go to **android/app/build.gradle** and update the **android/app/build.gradle**. For example:

   `android { compileSdkVersion 31}`
4. run `flutter clean`  in the terminal.

This solves the Mapping new ns Problem, but in the future you might want to upgrade your **gradle build tools version**, **compiled SDK Version** or **gradle version**, so these version numbers can be changed but **AGP**
and **Gradle** versions have to be compatible.
[here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle) you find which Android Gradle Plugin Version is compatible with which Gradle Version.