# Questions about updating Gradle in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle

I am working through the Net Ninja YouTube tutorial for Flutter. I just updated Flutter (or maybe Android Studio, whichever is arctic fox?) and now I am getting this error message whenever I try to run any basic app.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install /Users/dillonbond/AndroidStudioProjects/testapp3/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
Error launching application on sdk gphone64 arm64.
```

A google search led me to

[when I try to "sync project with gradle files" a warning pops up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66992420/when-i-try-to-sync-project-with-gradle-files-a-warning-pops-up)

People are saying I need to update Gradle. The click through solutions from this page are outdated or gone for me. Where do I input

```
codecompileSdkVersion(30)
buildToolsVersion("30.0.3")
```

solutions like this at? Do I put them somewhere in Android Studio in a dart file? Do I enter them into my command terminal? (I'm on a Mac).
All I know about Android Studio is the basic stuff from YouTube, I am very lost here. My programming skills are rudimentary. I'm not completely sure that the linked article even applies to my situation. I installed AS through the home brew pub thing if that makes any difference.

Thanks a million in advance to anyone that can help! I seriously appreciate it!

Comment: If you build your apps on emulator, then delete the emulator, and create new one. After you just go to android studio->File->Invalidate caches/restart and restart your android studio,

Answer (score 1):

It is already mentioned in your error that it is due to **insufficient storage**, delete some files from your real device and it will work.